# How do I get Polymer to work in IE11

Tags: polymer, internet-explorer-11

I have a simple polymer app:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=10" >
    <script type="text/javascript" src="components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="components/font-roboto/roboto.html">
    <link rel="import" href="viewer-app.html">

    <style>
        html,body {
            background-color: #fff;
            font-family: 'RobotoDraft', sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body fullbleed vertical layout unresolved>
    <template is="auto-binding">

        <viewer-app fit></viewer-app>
    </template>
</body>
```

the custom element 'viewer-app' does not even show up in f12 tools. I'm not getting any errors at all.

How do I get this to work?

Comment: Does this code work on other browsers cause I an a little doubt full about this line `<title>{{content.title}}</title>` You could try setting this using JavaScript and not Polymer Expressions, one reason is that polymer expressions only work with `template` tags with selected data.

Comment: that is a typeo. Content in viewer-app still does not render. And yes, it works in safari, FF, and Chrome.